# How to run a set of code before and after any tests in any class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, initialization

Here my test code:

```
public class Test1 {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.start();
    }

    // test methods...

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.stop();
    }      
}

public class Test2 {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.start();
    }

    // test methods...

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.stop();
    }
}

// ...
```

As you can see, I duplicate the start and stop calls to embedded tomcat in each Test class. How can I avoid this duplication with JUnit ?

Requirement:
   - The start and stop calls must be called ONCE for all test classes

**JUnit 4.11**

Comment: @wrongAnswer OP's using `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` which are executed before and after all the tests are executed, not per test execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to making a parent class that runs the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`. you can create a JUnit [Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules).  You can make your rule subclass [ExternalResource](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html) which has methods to override for adding behavior before and after executions (class or tests).

```
public class EmbeddedTomcatServer extends ExternalResource {

            ...

            @Override
            protected void before() throws Throwable {
                    EmbeddedTomcat.start();
            };

            @Override
            protected void after() {
                    EmbeddedTomcat.stop();
            };
    }
```

Then in your test use the `@ClassRule` which runs the server's `before()` and `after()` methods during `BeforeClass` and `AfterClass` time.

```
public class Test1 {

   @ClassRule
   public static EmbeddedTomcatServer tomcat = new EmbeddedTomcatServer();

   //tests as normal, no more @BeforeClass or @AfterClass

}

public class Test2 {

   @ClassRule
   public static EmbeddedTomcatServer tomcat = new EmbeddedTomcatServer();

   //tests as normal, no more @BeforeClass or @AfterClass

}
```

This solution might be better than the using a parent class because you can use this Rule in any test without having to change the parent class.

**EDIT**
only running the start() and stop() once

It is a little unclear if you mean running the start and stop once per test class (as your original code using @BeforeClass and @AfterClass)

Or if you want to run start and stop only once over ALL of the tests across the all the test classes that are run.

If you want to do the latter, @ClassRules are helpful here too.  Just create a test suite with the test classes to use and then put the ClassRule ONLY IN THE SUITE CLASS

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class AllTests {
   @ClassRule
   public static EmbeddedTomcatServer tomcat = new EmbeddedTomcatServer();

}
```

This will start tomcat when the AllTests suite starts and then stop tomcat when all the tests in the test suite have run.

Comment: What EmbeddedTomcatServer is ? (enum, class ...)

Comment: @Stephan it's a class, sorry, I fixed the code above Thanks!

Comment: Now there is an error: "The annotation @Rule is disallowed for this location"

Comment: Remove the `@Rule` from the EmbededTomcatServer class (and get rid of the end semicolon if the class is in it's own file).  Looks like the rule API changed over time so you don't need the @Rule anymore.  But still put the @ClassRule in the test classes

Comment: @Stephan also added answer for running start and stop only once

Answer (score 2):

If possible for your project, you can create a `TestParent` class which defines these `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods and make your `Test1` and `Test2` classes extend from it.

```
public class TestParent {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        EmbeddedTomcat.stop();
    }    
}

public class Test1 extends TestParent {
    //...
}

public class Test2 extends TestParent {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I just added a new requirement: `setUp` and `tearDown` must be called once.