# @ClassRule for all test classes

Tags: java, junit

I have ClassRule for example myRule and I want to apply this class rule for all test classes.
I use spring(integrations test) junit 4.

In case: I have to add all class this statement:

```
@ClassRule 
public static MyRule myRule = MyImplRule.getInstance();
```

Is there any way to not write this statement in all test classes but apply all test classes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look here:

[How to run a set of code before and after any tests in any class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342874/how-to-run-a-set-of-code-before-and-after-any-tests-in-any-class/26343242#26343242)

The best example for your case is to declare a testsuite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class AllTests {
  @ClassRule
  public static MyRule myRule = MyImplRule.getInstance();
}
```

The solution shows some other ways of running code for each test as well. It's quite good.

Comment: @SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class }) is this solution usable for add about 100 test classes in @SuiteClasses ?

Any other solutions ?